# Change shown entity namespace in WCF Data Service with custom reflection service

Tags: namespaces, entity, wcf-data-services

I'm trying to get my WCF Data Service to show a different entity namespace in the resulting xml from the entity's real namespace.

Consider this Netflix OData service [http://odata.netflix.com/v2/Catalog/Languages?$select=Name](http://odata.netflix.com/v2/Catalog/Languages)

Every entry looks like this

```
<entry>
    ...
    <category term="Netflix.Catalog.v2.Language" .../>
    ...
</entry>
```

In my own code the "category term" value is the namespace of my entity class and it's not as clean as I would like. In fact it's *OurProductName.CustomerName*.Web.RestApi.v2.Entities.Entityname.

Is it possible to change this by setting an attribute on the entity or some other way?

Regards,
Mathias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the reflection provider then this can't be changed currently. It is possible to write a custom provider in which case you can rename anything, but it's much more work.